The command '/bin/sh -c chown -R tomcat:root /app-root/runtime/data/ /opt/webserver/' returned a non-zero code: 1
I am currently building a Web application using Spring Boot, Java 17 and Angular. I am trying to create a tomcat image of my application using simple mvn install. I have provided plugins for maven to be able to build docker files, but whenever I'm trying to do that I'm getting this error.
Below is my Dockerfile:
FROM tomcat:10-jdk17-corretto
USER rootRUN echo "tomcat ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
ENV TOMCAT_HOME /opt/webserver
WORKDIR /apps
COPY ./target/app.war "/opt/webserver/webapps/ROOT.war"
RUN chown -R tomcat:root /app-root/runtime/data/ /opt/webserver/RUN chmod -R 777 /opt/webserver/bin/*.sh
USER tomcat
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/webserver/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]

These are the logs (I cannot provide the entire logs due to corporate data sensitivity):
[INFO] DOCKER> Step 1/13 : FROM tomcat:10-jdk17-corretto
[INFO] DOCKER> 
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> fe442f68f9c7
[INFO] DOCKER> Step 2/13 : USER root
[INFO] DOCKER> 
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> Using cache
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> d0101ca7dbae
[INFO] DOCKER> Step 3/13 : RUN echo "tomcat ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
[INFO] DOCKER> 
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> Using cache
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> 35a50c507da5
[INFO] DOCKER> Step 4/13 : ENV TOMCAT_HOME /opt/webserver
[INFO] DOCKER> 
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> Using cache
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> a5eb658b288a
[INFO] DOCKER> Step 6/13 : WORKDIR /apps
[INFO] DOCKER> 
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> Using cache
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> 841de4a6344e
[INFO] DOCKER> Step 7/13 : COPY ./target/app.war "/opt/webserver/webapps/ROOT.war"
[INFO] DOCKER> 
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> ac3448b249ad
[INFO] DOCKER> Step 8/13 : USER root
[INFO] DOCKER> 
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> Running in dd27c91f71ff
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> Removed intermediate container dd27c91f71ff
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> 08af8e389bb5
[INFO] DOCKER> Step 9/13 : RUN chown -R tomcat:root /app-root/runtime/data/ /opt/webserver/
[INFO] DOCKER> 
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> Running in 0ca54615c4ef
[INFO] DOCKER> [91mchown: invalid user: ‘tomcat:root’
[INFO] DOCKER> ---> Removed intermediate container 0ca54615c4ef
[ERROR] DOCKER> Unable to build image [../application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] : "The command '/bin/sh -c chown -R tomcat:root /app-root/runtime/data/ /opt/webserver/' returned a non-zero code: 1"  ["The command '/bin/sh -c chown -R tomcat:root /app-root/runtime/data/ /opt/webserver/' returned a non-zero code: 1" ]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  47.635 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-11T21:43:42+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.43.0:build (default) on project application: Unable to build image [../application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] : "The command '/bin/sh -c chown -R tomcat:root /app-root/runtime/data/ /opt/webserver/' returned a non-zero code: 1"  -> [Help 1]

I tried to remove that line which was creating issue, then the next line also gave a similar issue. Since I'm new to docker, I came here next in seek for help from the community!

you have not created the tomcat user you want to use. I have looked in the docker image and dont see any local user called tomcat in /etc/passwd

If you want to run this as the tomcat user then you will first need to create that user. Looking at the docker image you will need to install tools to manage users.
FROM tomcat:10-jdk17-corretto

# Create a tomcat user
RUN yum install -y shadow-utils
ARG USER=tomcat
ARG GROUP=tomcat
RUN groupadd -g 8256 "${GROUP}" && useradd --create-home -u 8256 -g 8256 "${USER}"

RUN echo "${USER} ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
ENV TOMCAT_HOME /opt/webserver
WORKDIR /apps
COPY ./target/app.war "/opt/webserver/webapps/ROOT.war"
RUN chown -R ${USER}:root /app-root/runtime/data/ /opt/webserver/
RUN chmod -R 777 /opt/webserver/bin/*.sh
USER ${USER}
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/webserver/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]

